# Aaccessing the same information from multiple places in C

Tags: c, dll

I want to be able to call two functions that both use the information stored in a variable say `FooBar`. I then have two functions `Foo` and `Bar`, that both perform an operation on the variable `FooBar`. `Foo` writes a value while `Bar` reads it. These functions are intended to be in a library (DLL) that return a value to the calling program. The data to be accessed will be a mixture of arrays/pointers to arrays, doubles and ints.

Would people be able to point me in the right direction for achieving such an operation?

Or am I looking at how to acquire the data in the wrong way, and there is a better way of doing this?

Regards

Comment: What am I missing? why you can't just send FooBar as a parameter?

Comment: Because as far as I understand, if you try and both read and write at the same time, the data can very well end up being corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach for this would be:

```
volatile my_int;

void foo(void)
{
    my_int++;
}

void bar(void)
{
    if (my_int)
        ...
    else
        ...
}
```

However, what do you want to achieve with this? Reference counting of some sort? Or is my_int supposed to be external to the library and hence needs to be "acquired"?
In that case, you might want to pass pointers to the library or use structures that you pass with each call.

It depends on whether or not your library code needs to have some internal state. If there is no internal state and the functionality rests solely inside the calls to foo and bar, then you should pass the appropriate data along with it.

Else, you might want to have some library initialization code and then queue buffers and register callback functions from the user program which the library then acts upon.

EDIT: If this question is about race conditions:

You need to be able to write to your data type atomically and read it atomically. Then you only have a non-critical race condition.
If you need to act on objects, arrays as a whole, then you will need to use mutual exclusion (mutex) locks.
The lock need to be a type that can be read/written atomically and then function foo will acquire the lock, edit data, release the lock. Function bar will do the same.
On truly parallel systems you will need hardware support as well as test-and-set commands, or you can still run into a live-lock.

Comment: For example I will be passing the DLL a pointer to an array of numbers, the DLL then performs some iterative function, and while this is running I am looking to get some measures of the quality of the data based on the iteration the function is at. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: To a large extent it is I suppose, and I am not sure if there are mutexes in C as opposed to C++. However what I am trying to understand is, what is the best way of processing information and acquiring a measure at each step such that I could if i so wished plot the progression of the iterations, as the iteration is being performed.

Comment: Well, first of all, you will need a pretty big data set for this to be significant. Secondly, mutexes aren't native to C++ nor C.

For your application to work in the way you want, you will probably have to queue some buffers for statistical data and use a callback. So user logic queues buffer0, buffer1. Library fills buffer0, calls callback, this unqueues buffer0, queues new buffer2. While callback is being processed, buffer1 is filled by library, then callback is called and so on.